# Redirect pgrep to a file twice in a single command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have an excercise to practice BASH in Linux and Im quite stuck. It says the following:

"List all process with the term BASH in their command line. Redirect the output to a file. Do this two more times adding it at the end of the file. Then list the commands ordered by PID. DO THIS IN JUST ONE COMMAND."

I KNOW Y MUST USE | AND >>....

I tried using something like this

pgrep -fl bash |

But i have no idea how to continue...

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Checkout `>>` which appends to a existing file

Comment: Check out `tee` which splits output into two places (writes to a file and to stdout).

Comment: and `| sort` "indterjected" into the pipeline, will the output in order. Good luck.

Comment: you probably want something like `{cmd; cmd; cmd} > file`

Comment: But that's hardly "a single command". My best guess as to what they're getting at is `for n in one two three; do ps | grep [b]ash; sleep 1; done | sort -n >output`

Comment: Or maybe `pgrep -fl bash >file; pgrep -fl bash >>file; pgrep -fl bash >>file; sort -un file` but that's four commands.

Comment: What does "DO THIS IN ONE COMMAND" mean? One can trivially accomplish anything in "one command" by writing a program that does whatever, and having the one command be "run my program"...

Comment: I think he meant in a one-liner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a way-

```
$for i in 1 2 3;do  ps -ef |grep bash >> out.log;done;cat out.log|sort -n
```

What you do here is you `grep` the word `bash` in processes one time and append it into a file named `out.log`, and then two times again (i.e. a total of 3 times). Then you `cat` the output of the `out.log` file in a `sort`ed manner.

Gives me output

```
users 4383078 4575750   0 09:56:29  pts/1  0:00 grep bash
users 4460634 4575750   0 09:54:06  pts/1  0:00 grep bash
users 4719330 4575750   0 09:57:28  pts/1  0:00 grep bash
```